# How to make the most of my PhD?

Tags: phd

I have recently applied to a PhD program (computational chemistry) in the United Kingdom. I am from the United Kingdom and I have autism. I have asked this question because I would like to build a scaffold of sorts as due to my autism I find it easier to understand when I have things planned in advance and know what to expect. I have listed below some of the things I am aware of and I would greatly appreciate if someone could point out things I may have missed or expand on the parts below (or both).

- From my understanding, my main priority is my research project.
- However, I've read online that people publish and review papers
  during their PhD. Is this something I should be doing and how do I go
  about doing it?
- Also, I've read people go to conferences, network and present their
  research. How do I know which conferences to go to and the best way to network?
- Also, will I have time during the first year to familiarise myself with the research material?

Comment: Published papers are the output of the research project, telling your peers what you actually accomplished. Some will say that you don't really understand an experiment until you write the paper...

Answer (score 1):

In a doctoral program you aren't a fish swimming alone. You will have assistance in the second and third bullet points. If you choose the right advisor and learn to interact with them well then they will advise you on lots of these things, including your research. With autism, that communication may be a difficult task until/unless you learn to master it.

Other students in the program can also be a resource, pointing you to things, say. But it requires communication.

Many of the tasks you learn by doing; reading, reviewing, writing. Don't worry that you don't start out with those skills. They are attained over time with practice.

The program is usually structured so that you have time for all of the important tasks, but you will be very busy and need to manage time effectively. But, through any available coursework, reading, and research you want to become a (novice) expert in your field. It can be done.

One problem you might actually wind up with is being too focused. Take time for your physical and mental health.

At any university you wind up at look to see if they have a counseling office that can give advice on managing autism. You aren't alone among academics by the way. Many top academics/researchers are on the spectrum. They have found ways to interact with people so that it isn't obvious. Some are quite famous speakers, actually.

Answer (score -1):

I already gave Buffy a thumbs-up. Just want to add some other stuff. The advice Buffy gives about getting assistance is very good.

Most PhDs have course work plus a thesis. While you are doing your course work you may or may not have a lot of free time. One class I took was given by a brand-new fresh-caught assistant prof. He had something to show us. He was proud that his one class managed to keep all the PhD students in our subject completely occupied for 3 straight months. One of his homework assignments took everybody in the class a full 60 hours to finish. The take-home final exam consumed about 80 hours of my time, and I was about in the middle for effort. We loved it and bragged about how much work we had done. Your mileage may vary.

Happily, the bullet-point items you list go together quite well.

For example, many people find that an excellent way to organize thoughts in your own mind is to write them down in a way that can be understood by others. Making it clear for others makes it clear for you. So writing journal articles and doing research are usually thought of as a very good pairing, even a required pairing.

Conferences are another form of this. Preparing a paper for presentation forces you to do another "run through." It may uncover things you didn't see the first however-many times you went through it. It's a different focus, a different light.

Seeing what other people are doing is also interesting. It may give you ideas about research you could do. Or it may just be interesting to know something you did not know before.

Conferences are also about contacts. Science has an aspect of exchanging ideas with other people. And it has the aspect of getting a job after your PhD. So brush up your social interaction skills and see if you can meet somebody at that conference. If they like your presentation maybe you can get a post-doc position with them.

Reading research journals is useful, even necessary. If you don't know the general trends of research in your field you are apt to try to publish stuff that has already been beaten to death.

Probably you can't read the entire literature in depth. Not unless you are truly unusually fast. Maybe start by looking at the table of contents, then read more detail in articles that seem to be interesting to your work.

You might try starting with some review articles. Depending on your field there will be journals that specialize in them. These are survey articles that give "the state of the art." You can also look for reports produced by working groups at various universities or labs. You can likely find reports from various labs and experiments that explain what they have been up to recently, and what they hope to do in the near future.

Comment: OP says they are in the UK; PhD programs in the UK may not have any coursework associated (I think it is most common that they do not).